# Angular Nodejs : Output is Undefined, Can't access the data from the server

Tags: node.js, angular, rxjs

I've just started programming in Node and Angular and I'm trying to run a simple application wherein I'm connecting my backend (localhost:3000) to my frontend and displaying the data. If the data I receive from the server when a get request is made is put in a .json file and I access it in the same folder then the data is being displayed.

But if I use the address of the api(http://localhost:3000/purchase) from which the data has been picked I get an undefined error in the browser.

This is the error it shows in the browser:

```
ContactsComponent.html:2 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'Empno' of undefined
    at Object.eval [as updateRenderer] (ContactsComponent.html:2)
    at Object.debugUpdateRenderer [as updateRenderer] (core.js:22503)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:21878)
    at callViewAction (core.js:22114)
    at execComponentViewsAction (core.js:22056)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:21879)
    at callViewAction (core.js:22114)
    at execComponentViewsAction (core.js:22056)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:21879)
    at callWithDebugContext (core.js:22767)
```

**This is the Output from my server (http://localhost:3000/purchase) on Postman:**

```
{
    "Empno": "113       ",
    "Ename": "Mary      ",
    "Sal": "15220     ",
    "Deptno": "DP        "
}
```

**This is the code in angular for the service:**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { map, filter, switchMap, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Contact } from './contact';
import { HttpErrorResponse, HttpResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { retry } from 'rxjs/operators';



@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class ContactService {
  contact: Contact[];
  //  configUrl1 = '../assets/test.json';
 configUrl1 = 'http://localhost:3000';


  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
  // retrieving contacts

  getPurchase() {
    return this.http.get(this.configUrl1);
  }

}

**This is the code for the Component:**

import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {  ContactService } from '../contact.service';
import { Contact } from '../contact';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-contacts',
  templateUrl: './contacts.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./contacts.component.scss'],
  providers: [ContactService]
})
export class ContactsComponent implements OnInit {
  contact: Contact;
  Empno: string;
    Ename: string;
    Sal: string;
    Deptno: string;


  constructor(private contactService: ContactService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.contactService.getPurchase()
      .subscribe((data: Contact) => this.contact = {...data});
    }

}
```

**This is the code for defining the structure for contact:**

```
export class Contact {
    Empno: string;
    Ename: string;
    Sal: string;
    Deptno: string;
    }
```

This is the code for the HTML file of the contact component:

```
<div class= "container">
  <p>Its Working here also</p>

    {{contact.Empno}}
    {{contact.Ename}}

</div>
```

**Server Side code:
App.js**

```
//importing modules
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var cors = require('cors');
var mssql = require('mssql');
var path = require('path');
var app = express();

const route = require('./routes/route');
//port no
const port = 3000;

// adding middlewear - cors
app.use(cors());

// adding middlewear - bodyparser
// app.use(bodyparser.json());

// static files
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

//creating routes
app.use('/purchase', route);

//testing 
app.get('/', (req,res)=>{
    res.send('foobar');
});

// //bind the port
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log('Server started at port: ' + port);
});

// create application/json parser
var jsonParser = bodyParser.json()
// app.use(bodyParser.json({ type: 'application/*+json' }))

// POST /login gets urlencoded bodies
app.post('/login', jsonParser, function (req, res) {
  if (!req.body) return res.sendStatus(400)
  res.send('welcome, ' + req.body.username)
})
```

**route.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();
const sql = require('mssql');
const config = 'mssql://vpn:vpn1@ASPL-AVG:1433/Sampledb';


app.use(bodyParser.json());

var jsonParser = bodyParser.json()

router.get('/', jsonParser,(req,res, next)=>{
  var conn = new sql.ConnectionPool(config);
  conn.connect().then((conn) => {
    var sqlreq = new sql.Request(conn);
    sqlreq.execute('SelEmpl10', function(err, recordset) {
      res.json(recordset.recordsets[0][1]);
      console.log(recordset.recordsets[0][1]); 

    })
    })
  });

//add purchase order
router.post('/' , jsonParser ,(req, res, next) => {
    //logic to add record
    console.log(req.body.username);
    var conn = new sql.ConnectionPool(config);
    conn.connect().then((conn) => {
      var sqlreq = new sql.Request(conn);
      sqlreq.input('Username', sql.VarChar(30), req.body.username);
      sqlreq.input('Password', sql.VarChar(30), req.body.password);
      sqlreq.input('Email', sql.VarChar(30), req.body.email);
      sqlreq.input('Name', sql.VarChar(30), req.body.name);
      sqlreq.execute('saveuser').then(function(err, recordsets, returnValue, affected) {
        console.dir(recordsets);
        console.dir(err);
        conn.close();
      }).catch(function(err) {
            res.json({msg: 'Failed to add contact'});
            console.log(err);
      });
    });
  })



//delete purchase order
router.delete('/:id', (req, res, next) => {
    //logic to delete record

});

module.exports = router;
```

The data received from SQL is this:

```
{
    "recordsets": [
        [
            {
                "Empno": "112       ",
                "Ename": "john      ",
                "Sal": "142500    ",
                "Deptno": "CS        "
            },
            {
                "Empno": "113       ",
                "Ename": "Mary      ",
                "Sal": "15220     ",
                "Deptno": "DP        "
            }
        ]
    ],
    "recordset": [
        {
            "Empno": "112       ",
            "Ename": "john      ",
            "Sal": "142500    ",
            "Deptno": "CS        "
        },
        {
            "Empno": "113       ",
            "Ename": "Mary      ",
            "Sal": "15220     ",
            "Deptno": "DP        "
        }
    ],
    "output": {},
    "rowsAffected": [
        2
    ],
    "returnValue": 0
}
```

After adding the parameters in Node the output is this:

```
{
    "Empno": "113       ",
    "Ename": "Mary      ",
    "Sal": "15220     ",
    "Deptno": "DP        "
}
```

Comment: `contact` is undefined when the component initially loads, which would cause the undefined error. Either use the Async pipe or use ngIf to only render the div when contact has actually loaded.

Comment: I've added another <div *ngIf=contact> and now I'm getting the error: `Message: "Http failure during parsing for http://localhost:3000/"
name: "HttpErrorResponse"
ok: false
status: 200
statusText: "OK"
url: "http://localhost:3000/"`

Comment: Please reproduce step by step, let's try : `this.contactService.getPurchase()
      .subscribe((data) => { console.log(data); });
    }`  and check value is string or variable

Comment: @ThienHoang It's giving me the same error as above. The data is not being received for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is possibly connected to the use of `bodyParser`. It may be trying to parse already parsed JSON.  Basically add the parser once at the top level and remove it from the routes. Also it may be connected to using json() instead of send(). I’ve had issues where if the data had a property named data, it could cause json parse/stringify to fail.

Try the following. In `App.js` reintroduce the line `app.use(bodyParser.json())`, this only needs to be added once at a top level location such as this entry file. Also from this file remove `jsonParser` middleware from the `/login` POST route:

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();

const route = require('./routes/route');
//port no
const port = 3000;

// adding middlewear - cors
app.use(cors());

// adding middlewear - bodyparser
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// static files
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

//creating routes
app.use('/purchase', route);

//testing 
app.get('/', (req,res)=>{
    res.send('foobar');
});

// //bind the port
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log('Server started at port: ' + port);
});

// POST /login gets urlencoded bodies
app.post('/login', function (req, res) {
  if (!req.body) return res.sendStatus(400)
  res.send('welcome, ' + req.body.username)
})
```

In `route.js`, remove the `bodyParser.json()` and `jsonParser` middleware, it's already included at the top level as `app.use(bodyParser.json());` applies it to **all** routes/verbs:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
var app = express();
const sql = require('mssql');
const config = 'mssql://vpn:vpn1@ASPL-AVG:1433/Sampledb';

router.get('/',(req, res, next)=>{
  var conn = new sql.ConnectionPool(config);
  conn.connect().then((conn) => {
    var sqlreq = new sql.Request(conn);
    sqlreq.execute('SelEmpl10', function(err, recordset) {
      res.json(recordset.recordsets[0][1]);
      console.log(recordset.recordsets[0][1]); 
    })
    })
  });

//add purchase order
router.post('/', (req, res, next) => {
    //logic to add record
    console.log(req.body.username);
    var conn = new sql.ConnectionPool(config);
    conn.connect().then((conn) => {
      var sqlreq = new sql.Request(conn);
      sqlreq.input('Username', sql.VarChar(30), req.body.username);
      sqlreq.input('Password', sql.VarChar(30), req.body.password);
      sqlreq.input('Email', sql.VarChar(30), req.body.email);
      sqlreq.input('Name', sql.VarChar(30), req.body.name);
      sqlreq.execute('saveuser').then(function(err, recordsets, returnValue, affected) {
        console.dir(recordsets);
        console.dir(err);
        conn.close();
      }).catch(function(err) {
            res.json({msg: 'Failed to add contact'});
            console.log(err);
      });
    });
  })

// delete purchase order
router.delete('/:id', (req, res, next) => {
    //logic to delete record
});

module.exports = router;
```

If that still fails, try just using `res.send()` instead of `res.json()`, even just for troubleshooting purposes.

The last thing that I'd recommend is sending an actual error or at least some type of `4xx` or `5xx` status code so that Angular HttpClient can treat it as an actual error instead of a successful HTTP request with a `200` status code.

Hopefully that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Add a safe navigation operation to the `contact` variable.

```
<div class= "container">
  <p>Its Working here also</p>
    {{contact?.Empno}}
    {{contact?.Ename}}
</div>
```

which is equivalent to `contact != null ? contact.Empno: null`

### Update:

Also, add Error Handling code:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.contactService.getPurchase().subscribe(
    (data: Contact) => {
      this.contact = {...data};
    },
    error => {
      console.log("Error Occured: "+ error);
    }
  );
}
```

Comment: I've added another <div *ngIf=contact> and now I'm getting the error: `Message: "Http failure during parsing for http://localhost:3000/" name: "HttpErrorResponse" ok: false status: 200 statusText: "OK" url: "http://localhost:3000/"` also `SyntaxError: Unexpected token H in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse`

Comment: @AviralGoyal Your response should be in a proper JSON format. Also, your variable name and JSON response variable name should match. `Empno` in Contact class should match with `Empno` variable in JSON response (It is Case sensitive).

Comment: The response when copied and pasted from postman into a .json file and pointing to that URL is gives the result. So case sensitive or Proper JSON is not the problem, as far as I can tell. I've mentioned all the values in my question. Please tell me if i can provide you some more info, which might help in figuring out the problem.

Comment: @AviralGoyal Change your `configUrl1` to `http://localhost:3000/purchase`

Comment: That's when i get the error. In the other case where I'm referring to the same output from the server in a .json file, the data gets displayed.

Comment: @AviralGoyal If you are adding some headers while sending request from `Postman`, then you have to do the same while sending request from angular. Angular is not getting the JSON data, thats why it is showing that error. It is receiving this as response: `Message: "Http failure during parsing for http://localhost:3000/" name: "HttpErrorResponse" ok: false status: 200 statusText: "OK" url: "http://localhost:3000/"`

Comment: This error `Unexpected token H in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse` means that it is reading `"Http failure during parsing for http://localhost:3000/"` message as response, which is not in JSON format.

Comment: I have not added any headers. This is the same result I will get when I open the link in the Chrome Browser. But I think I'll have to convert the data being sent to JSON, irrespective of the fact that it is already JSON. Let me see what I can find for the same.

Comment: @AviralGoyal Have you tried this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53967393/angular-nodejs-output-is-undefined-cant-access-the-data-from-the-server/53967532?noredirect=1#comment94773103_53967393

Comment: Yeah I've tried it, it's giving me the same error. Should I just upload my entire code on a Git Hub repository and share the Link? The only problem is that I'm using SQL Server as my backend. After query execution the result is passed to my Node Server which intern forwards the data to the Angular part. But for some reason Angular is not able to fetch the data.

Comment: I've added the server side code as well. Please see if you can find the problem here.

Comment: @AviralGoyal Add error handling code. It's the best way to get the actual cause. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Okay I updated the code as you said now I'm getting the error: [object Object]. I have also simplified my backend code to just pass json data res.send(obj) and obj = {Empno: "123" , Ename: "Joe"}. So whatever the error is the data is just not getting sent to the client end.

Comment: @AviralGoyal Remove `"Error Occured: "+ ` from console.log to see the whole error message (Usually we take the error object and print only the message). Mostly it will be the same error which you got. This verifies that server is responding back to angular with error and not the actual data.

Comment: Hi I've removed the error occurred part and I'm getting the original error again : `HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 200, statusText: "OK", url: "http://localhost:3000/", ok: false, …}
error:
error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token H in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse (<anonymous>) at XMLHttpRequest.onLoad (http://localhost:5600/vendor.js:7510:51)`

Comment: Let me make a fresh project and try to push a normal string first. I think that should help me figure out the problem. If you do see any problems here let me know. But thank you so much for your help. :)